# How to change the way categories links are shown in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

my question is what should I edit in wordpress files so my categories links shows in any theme doesn't show like that www.mysite.com/category/category-1 , and make it show the way I want it for example : category-1.mysite.com or even change the link to another website www.mysite2.com/ , I mean here just changing the links and not making category-1.mysite.com shows www.mysite.com/category/category-1 contents.

Answer (score 0):

1. as a subdomain: you could do it simply using a rule in your .htaccess file
2. as another website: I don't really get the point here but you would need to make a custom plugin or simply some function in your function.php file that overrides the filter "category_link" provided by WordPress in order to return your custom link in function of the category ID passed in parameter. (see this [WordPress codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Category_and_Term_Filters))

See also: this [forum topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-category-link-to-page-link)